# Why can not add annotations on mapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

Why can not add annotations on mapView??? I get array with annotation, then try to put them to map((( map is empty( this my code and viewAnnotation method where i find mistake with my own annotation class(

```
 @implimentation MyClass {
     NSMutableArray *_annotation;
}
 _agents = [[Database sharedDatabase] agentsList];
_mapView.delegate = self;
[_agents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [_annotations addObject:[[[BronAgentMapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithAgency:obj] autorelease]];
}];
NSLog(@"num of annot = %d", _annotations.count); //num of annot = 120
_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

if (_showUserLocation) {
    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
[_annotations enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [_mapView addAnnotation: obj];
}];
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    _annotations = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
}

return self;
 }



    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // in case it's the user location, we already have an annotation, so just return nil
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // handle our three custom annotations
    //
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BronAgentMapViewAnnotation class]])
    {
        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString *bronAgentMapViewAnnotationIdentifier = @"BronAgentMapViewAnnotationIdentifier";

        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
                [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:bronAgentMapViewAnnotationIdentifier];

        if (pinView == nil)
        {
            // if an existing pin view was not available, create one
            MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:bronAgentMapViewAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];

            customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
            customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;
            customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

            // add a detail disclosure button to the callout which will open a new view controller page
            //
            // note: you can assign a specific call out accessory view, or as MKMapViewDelegate you can implement:
            //  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;
            //
            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [rightButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(showDetails:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            rightButton.tag = [(BronAgentMapViewAnnotation *) annotation annotationId];
            customPinView.hidden = [(BronAgentMapViewAnnotation *) annotation isHidden];
            customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return customPinView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView.tag = [(BronAgentMapViewAnnotation *) annotation annotationId];
            pinView.hidden = [(BronAgentMapViewAnnotation *) annotation isHidden];
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Can help?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-drop-a-pin-on-map-with-mapkit-api/   see this link...

Comment: are you sure that your array is not empty after addobject ?

Comment: Yes i am sure, i use NSLog(@"%@", _annotation.count) to see count of objects...

Comment: ok, how is your implementation of viewforannotation ? can you add it on your post

Comment: The problem - that i create my own class of annotation "BronAgentMapViewAnnotation", and when i check in (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation     if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BronAgentMapViewAnnotation class]])
    {
//} return nil;       my annotation not in this class and return nil(

Comment: Seems that my Annotation is kind of class MKUserLocation

Comment: What does `isHidden` return?  Log the coordinates of the annotations and make sure they're valid and make sure you're looking for the annotations at those coordinates.  Do you call removeAnnotation(s) anywhere?  After the addAnnotation loop, put `NSLog(@"_mapView.annotations.count=%d", _mapView.annotations.count);` and see what it says.  Is `_mapView` an IBOutlet and if so, is it hooked up properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the map delegate. The annotationViews are assigned there.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

Comment: the problem is that does not fall into this function(((

Comment: Seems you did not initialise the mutablearray?

Comment: NSMutableArray* _annotations = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: i initialize this(  him count is 120 (

Comment: Problem in this -  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

Comment: Where do you allocate the mutable array?
_annotation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; You should do that before you add objects to it.

Comment: the array contains objects, count of them 120, i can see them in NSLog

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your own annotationView's class and call viewforannotation like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[yourAnnotationClass class]]) {
    yourAnnotationView *annotationView = (yourAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annotation"];
    if (!annotationView)
        annotationView = [[yourAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation" delegate:self];
    else
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    return annotationView;
}
       return [_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your _mapView IBOutlet to the MKMapView you have in your interface? Without it it doesn't know that the MKMapView it is drawing on screen is the one you are calling _mapView and adding annotations to, so it won't ask to draw those annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    mapView=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    mapView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    mapView.zoomEnabled=YES;
    mapView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    [self annotationPlacing];

    // 36.777313,-119.706405  36.120838,-115.33682  47.798397,-121.519775    47.606337,-122.330618

}

-(void)annotationPlacing 
{
    NSArray *arrLat=[[NSArray   alloc]initWithObjects:@"36.777313",@"36.120838",@"47.798397",@"47.606337", nil];
    NSArray *arrLong=[[NSArray   alloc]initWithObjects:@"-119.706405",@"-115.33682",@"-121.519775",@"-122.330618", nil];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude=[[arrLat objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];
        location.longitude=[[arrLong objectAtIndex:i]floatValue];

        MKPointAnnotation *annottion=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        annottion.coordinate=location;
        annottion.title=@"India";
        annottion.subtitle=@"Hyderabad";

        [arrAnnotation addObject:annottion];

        [mapView addAnnotation:annottion];

    }
}
```